# How to control acquisition time in LabVIEW?

Tags: while-loop, labview

I just want to control the data acquisition time in this while loop, any ideas? In this case I can calculate how many files I can acquire during a constant time?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Kind regards,

Aileen[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To control sampling rate, you can use DAQmx Timing.vi. To configure task you can use create task.vi.

To know the exact duration of your loop you can use tick count(ms) function and shift registers: [image]

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you intend to acquire data continuously, you'll want to place the Timing, Start, and Stop VIs outside of the loop, or build in logic so that they only execute once per intended acquisition session. It's unclear from the question picture if that's the goal.